# issue in a regexp

Tags: regex

I'm using the following expression:

```
/^[alopinme]{5}$/
```

This regexp take me words from a set of words with letters contained within the brackets.

well, now i need to add some more functionality to such expression because i need that the fetched words could contain ONLY one more letter from another set of letters. Let's say that i want to get words formed with letters from set A and **could** (if exist) contain one more letter from set B.

i'm trying to guess how could i complete my regular expression but i do not find the right way.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here i post an example:

```
SELECT sin_acentos FROM Finder.palabras_esp WHERE sin_acentos REGEXP '^[tehsolm]{5}$'
```

This expression choose me words like: helms, moths meths homes and so on.....

but i need to add a set B of letters and get words that could contain ONLY one from such set. Lets say I have another set of letters [xzk] so the expression could get more words but only with the possibility of choosing one letter from set B.

The result could get words like: mozes, hoxes, tozes, and so on... if you check such words, you can see that most of letters for every word are from set A but only one from set B.

Comment: What language. Regex is slightly different on different languages.

Comment: well, i'm doing it in mysql and in action script. In both languages i use such expression. i can adapt it in both.

Comment: Having several examples of what should be matched *and* what shouldn't be would really help here.

Comment: So you are writing a tool which helps you win "Scrabble" or "Words with friends". Cheater! ;-) Anyway, it is a nice use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the one of the other characters should appear exactly once, you can use:

```
^(?=.{5}$)[alopinme]*(?:[XYZ][alopinme]*)?$
```

- `(?=.{5}$)` - Check the string is 5 characters long, even before matching. (this might not work on MySql)
- `[alopinme]*` - Characters from A
- `(?:[XYZ][alopinme]*)?` - Optional - one character from B, and some more from A.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/aw6l561Int

Or, for if you want them up to 3 times, for example:

```
^(?=.{5}$)[alopinme]*(?:[XYZ][alopinme]*){0,3}$
```

Comment: Hi Kobi... I'm checking your expression and mit arise an error in mysql -> Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp. I used this: SELECT sin_acentos FROM Finder.palabras_esp WHERE sin_acentos REGEXP '^(?=.{5}$)[ABCEPOXYZ]*(?:[XYZ][ABCEPOXYZ]*)?$'

Comment: @domoindal - As I've said - I doubted it worked on MySql, but it will work on ActionScript. I posted it before your sample code, but I hope it can be useful anyway...

Comment: ahhhhh, perfect... i will try it in action script. Such expression fetch me words of 5 letters with words formed by letters from this set [alopinme] and only 1 letter from [XYZ] in case there is any?  If so, such expression is much more powerfull than the one I'm using due to i do not need to add aditional filters.

Comment: Is there anyway in adding to your expression a filter which avoid letters from set A be repeated in the result?

Comment: @domoindal - There are many ways to play with the pattern. First - yes, it is possible. for example, adding something like `^(?![alopinme]*([alopinme])[alopinme]*\1)` (for the first group), or `^(?!.*(.).*\1)` (for the whole word). But: **1.** Your next question might be about including a letter more than once: `[aaabc]`, which will not work easily. **2.** It's getting ugly.

Comment: Yes, a letter can be repeted within set A more than once, so, what would you advice me?

Comment: @domoindal - I'd advice to write code - it is almost trivial to count letters according to your sets. Maybe you should think about a specialized data structure for all 5 letter words - for example, sorting them by letter, and using that as a key in a dictionary or a db (just brainstorming)

Answer (score 2):

Since the words that you are looking for are all five-character long, I can think of a rather ugly expression that would do the trick: let's say `[alopinme]` is your base set, and `[xyz]` is your optional set. Then the expression

```
/^([alopinmexyz][alopinme]{4}|[alopinme][alopinmexyz][alopinme]{3}|[alopinme]{2}[alopinmexyz][alopinme]{2}|[alopinme]{3}[alopinmexyz][alopinme]|[alopinme]{4}[alopinmexyz])$/
```

should allow five-letter words of the structure that you are looking for.

In general, a need to count anything makes your regex non-readable. Problems like this one are good to illustrate this point: it is much easier to write `/^[alopinmexyz]{5}$/` expression, and add an extra step in code to check that `[xyz]` appears in the text no more than once. You can even use a regexp to do the additional check:

```
/^[^xyz]*[xyz]?[^xyz]*$/
```

The result in SQL would look as follows:

```
SELECT sin_acentos
FROM Finder.palabras_esp
WHERE sin_acentos REGEXP '^[tehsolmxyz]{5}$'      -- Length == 5, all from tehsolm+xyz
  AND sin_acentos REGEXP '^[^xyz]*[xyz]?[^xyz]*$' -- No more than one character from xyz
```

Comment: But OP shouldn't really actually use this regex :) Why not write some simple string manipulation code that can handle this?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, this expression '/^[^xyz]*[xyz]?[^xyz]*$/' means that filter only one letter within such set?

Comment: @domoindal Yes, the second expression would fail if there is more than one character from the extension set `[xyz]`.